# What are some uses for the HDMI port?

Tags: hdmi

My MID came with an HDMI port and cable. I have not seen this on any other device. What are some uses for this?

Comment: SE doesn't do lists; see the [FAQ].  Lie's answer is good but if you're unsure of what HDMI is I recommend Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for video out, you can connect them to your TV to get an even larger screen, for example, to watch videos. Or you might be able to use it for doing presentations on a projector, instead of using a laptop.